# Attributes of other types such as Thread in UML?

Tags: c#, uml

So I am quite new to UML and was wondering how to represent attributes of other types in UML. Can I just visualize it as a private attribute of type Thread?

I went through tutorials and searched online. The answer is probably really simple, but I couldn't find it or explain it to myself.

So lets suppose I have code like:

```
private Thread m_Thread = null;
```

How do I display this in a UML class diagram?

Comment: Where would you need that? If you would have it in something like `class MyClass { 
private Thread m_Thread = null; }`, then you could simply visualize it in a UML class diagram as a private attribute of type `Thread` with a default value of `null`.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if I could use types other than string, int, bool, etc. Definitely makes sense!

Comment: Any UML tool worth its salt should allow you to let attributes have any type you want.

Comment: Since you are talking about "code" I'm just assuming you want to show behavior?

Comment: Im using a class diagram. Corak explained it perfectly, because my not well formulated question was if I can use other attributes types such as thread.

Comment: You should make an edit to your question so it's clear. That way others can profit from your questions and the answers given to it.

Comment: Changed it to the best of my ability. If you have any ideas on how I could improve it, please share!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to represent that:

[image]

The `-` represents the `private` part, name and type as you can guess and the assignment is the initial value.

Another way would be this:

[image]

Here you see the private owned property name `mThread` (represented by the dot symbol) near the according class. AFAIK you can not show an initial value this way, at least I never used it here. But it gives a much better picture how classes relate to each other.

---

*Answer to the original question which still holds true, though not fitting to the edited one:*

You do not display behavior in a class diagram, only static relations. In order to show behavior you create a sequence diagram (https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html) and use a life line for a class instance.

Comment: Your question update is fine. I leave my answer, although it does no longer really fit the new question.

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed to have an attribute of a type not equal to one of the primitive types predefined by UML, but only if you define this other type as a classifier somewhere else in your UML model. In your example, your can write the following attribute in the attribute section of a class symbol:

`- m_Thread : Thread = null`

provided you also model a class called `Thread`.